# pythonic way to fill an array with geometric cumulative function

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to fill an array with the position of the boundary of `n_cells` (starting from 0 up to `n_cells+1`) with the size of the cell in geometric progression (with parameter `c`) and the total size will be thick (thus `x[0]=0` and `x[n_cells]=thick`)

I have this which works:

```
n_cells=10
c=0.9
thick=2

x = np.zeros(n_cells + 1)
x_0=thick * (c - 1) / (c**n_cells - 1)
for i in range(n_cells):
    x[i+1] = x[i] + x_0 * c ** i
```

Since I'm learning, is there a simpler pythonic comprehension way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way by using numpy stuff:

```
x_0=thick * (c - 1) / (c**n_cells - 1)
x=np.cumsum(np.concatenate(([0],np.geomspace(x_0, x_0*c**(n_cells-1), num=n_cells))))
```

however readability is not improved (I don't like the concatenate) so I wouldn't mark this answer as more "pythonic" just shorter

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `numba.njit` module. It will speed up your code. It is not more pythonic but it will be faster if you use a larger `n_cells`.
See the example below

```
import numpy as np
from numda import njit
@njit
def fast_goem():
    n_cells=10
    c=0.9
    thick=2
    x = np.zeros(n_cells + 1)
    x_0=thick * (c - 1) / (c**n_cells - 1)
    for i in range(n_cells):
        x[i+1] = x[i] + x_0 * c ** i
    return x
```